# During servelt running in Tomcat Server( Local) in Intellij Json object can not be loaded

Tags: java, json, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have written one jsp and corrosponding servelt in Intellij and running it in Tomcat local server from Intellij. Now without json file if I pass some normal text as output the servlet is working fine,but with json object its showing

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
    Servlet.UserInt.processRequest
---I have already imported json-simple -1,1.jar in external libraries so that its compiling but during servlet running it cant be loaded.
I also have created under web one folder named lib and have placed json and servet jar files there.

enter code here

UserInt.java---

```
public class UserInt extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
      processRequest(request,response);
    }

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request,response);
    }

   /* @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserInt{} " + super.toString();
    }*/

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        try{
            String query=request.getParameter("searchquery");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("query", query);
            json.put("country", "India");
            String output = json.toString();

            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
           writer.write("output");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
       }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Index.jsp---

```
 <form action="Servlet.UserInt" method="get" id="search-box">
    <input type="text" class="search" name="searchquery" size="20" maxlength="120" placeholder="search...">
    <input type="submit" class="button"value="Search">

    <div class="set-parameter"><h3>User-Requirements</h3>
      <i>Number of pages you want to see ?</i><input type="text" name="k" class="simple"/>
    </div>

[enter image description here][1]
  </form>
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this error? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if correct org.json jar-file is imported.

I created simple project in IDEA with such dependencies in pom.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-eu.nuxeo.org</id>
      <url>https://maven-eu.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Servlet:

```
package servlets;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet ("/myservlet.do")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("query", "query");
        json.put("country", "India");
        String output = json.toString();

        out.println(output);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Hello Servlet Get
{"country":"India","query":"query"}
```

I run it on WildFly JBoss 10.2.0.Final